# Bind some arbitrary value to route in Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-frameworks, werkzeug

How can I elegantly bind some arbitrary value and flask route? Suppose, I want to access this value in my session interface implementation or in `before_request` hook.

Now I'm doing it in such way:

```
@app.route('/foo/<bar>', defaults={'_my_val': True}):
def foo(bar, _my_val):  # this is ugly hack
    pass
```

And access this value through request object like this:

```
class MyRequest(flask.Request):
    def get_my_val(self):
        return (self.url_rule.defaults or {}).get('_my_val', False)
```

But it looks like a hack.

**UPD:** Looks like it can be done by extending `werkzeug.routing.Rule` class and adding `**kwargs` to its constructor. Is it ok to override Rule class in flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I ended up overriding flask's Request and Rule classes:

```
# here app is a Flask current application object
from flask import Request as FlaskRequest
from werkzeug.routing import Rule as FlaskRule

class Request(FlaskRequest):
    def is_foo(self):
        return bool(self.url_rule._foo) if self.url_rule else False

    def get_bar(self):
        return getattr(self.url_rule, '_bar')

class Rule(FlaskRule):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for param in ('_foo', '_bar'):
            setattr(self, param, kwargs.pop(param, None))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# app initialization
app.request_class = Request
app.url_rule_class = Rule

# route example        
@app.route('/path', _foo=True, _bar='baz')
def route():
    pass
```